# Conditional Formatting based on date and value in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, conditional-formatting

I am trying to return the color for a score based on the date for the score and the score itself. Scoring has used different cut-offs over time:

```
Table 1
Date1   Score  Color
Sep-16   24    [should be red]
Jul-16   6     [should be green]
Apr-14   12    [should be yellow]
...      ...   ...

Table 2
Date2   Red Orange  Yellow  Green
Aug-16  20  15       9.5    0
Jul-16  20  15.5     9.5    0
Apr-16  20  15       9.5    0
Mar-15  19  14       7      0
Feb-15  20  13       8.5    0
Jan-15  19  14       7      0
Apr-14  19  14       7      0
```

I want to place a formula in the "Color" cell that will evaluate Table 2 and return the column name for instances where the date in date1 is the most recent instance where it is greater than date 2, and for which the score given on table 1 is equal to or larger than the score given on table 2 for the correct row.

Thanks,

Comment: So if the date in Table 1 is Jul-16, should it look in the Jul-16 row in Table 2, or Aug-16 ?

Comment: Tom - if the date in Table 1 is Jul-16 it should look in the Jul-16 row. I have a solution, but it a ton of conditional if statements, starting at the top right of Table 2 and looking across and down.

Answer (score 1):

You need nested approximate lookups. This would be easier if your data was sorted the other way around. At least table 2 should have the columns in ascending order, instead of descending, so the match function can return the correct position of the number with an approximate match.

If you can arrange the columns in Table2 in the order Date2, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red, then the following formula will be possible.

```
=INDEX(Table3[[#Headers],[Green]:[Red]],MATCH([@Score],INDEX(Table3[Green],IFERROR(MATCH([@Date1],Table3[Date2],-1),1)):INDEX(Table3[Red],IFERROR(MATCH([@Date1],Table3[Date2],-1),1)),1))
```

This uses structured references, which accommodates rows being inserted into the tables without breaking the formulas.

[image]

Now you can use conditional formatting based on the cell values in column C.

Comment: This is great, but it works better if I've sorted the second table from oldest at the top to newest at the bottom. It's giving me trouble with Feb 15, and April - August 2016. I'll have to play around with the match types some more, but I think the basic formula is solid.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison, I have chosen to keep the lookup table (in Sheet2 rather than in an actual table) the same as in the question i.e. both tables are sorted from largest to smallest or most recent to least recent and the MATCHes both have -1 as the third argument:-

[image]